# Appcelerator: remote connect WebView to Chrome

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

Some time ago I was able to remote debug a webview in Chrome to debug html-errors. But now, it isn't working anymore on my Android-phone, I'm not able to connect (In Chrome: More Tools > Developer Tools > Remote Devices ... where my remote devices says "connected".

The lines I added (in varying composition) to tiapp.xml:

> < property name="appc-security-debugger-detect">false< /property>
>       < application android:debuggable="true" />
>       < disable_error_screen>true< /disable_error_screen>

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.
In tiapp.xml, these two elements needs te be in this order:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"/>
<application android:debuggable="true"/>
```

... instead of:

```
<application android:debuggable="true"/>
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"/>
```

... looks like a bug to me.